# Dynamic <select> with Zurb Foundation Custom Forms

Tags: select, dynamic, zurb-foundation

I'm building a Web App with Zurb Foundation and I need to dynamically add/remove `<option></option>` to `<select>`. After adding/removing I call `Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($('#mySelectID'));` but it doesn't "refreshes". Someone has a clue why not?!

Comment: Sorry guys, I've founded the problem, I should have used `TRUE` in `Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($('#mySelectID'));`, so like this `Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($('#mySelectID'), true);` it is now working.

Comment: If you find the answer to your own question, please consider to post it as an answer.